# How to loop only categories without posts (+ show category featured image with acf)

Tags: categories, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I want to create on my blog a category loop with the featured image.
But i don't know how i do that technical.

You should only see a list of categories and click on them to get the category site. It's like a article loop only with categories.

Thank you for any help :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, in WP the word "loop" is mainly related to posts. It's easier to say that you want to display categories.

All you have to do is to get them using [`get_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) function and display them.

```
<?php
    $categories = get_categories( array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    ) );
    if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) :
?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ( $categories as $category ) : ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo esc_attr(get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $category->name ); ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And if you want to change the category title to some ACF custom field, then change this part:

```
<?php echo esc_html( $category->name ); ?>
```

to:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_field('<FIELD_NAME>', $category), 'full' ); ?>
```

PS. Remember to change  to real name of the field. It should return the ID of an image (and not the array - you should set it in field setting). You can also change the 'full' size to some other size.

Comment: hmm... put the wp_get_attachement_image in the code, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_field('cat_thumbnail_image', $category), 'thumbnail' ); ?>

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is [`get_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) function.

You can use it as follows, note that I assumed the featured image url is stored in a meta of the category which may not be your case:

```
$categories = get_categories();
if(count($categories)) {
    foreach($categories as $cat) {
        $catID = $cat->term_id;
        $img = get_term_meta($catID, 'featured_image', true);
        $url = esc_url( get_category_link( $catID ) );
        echo "<a href='$url'><img src='$img' /></a>";
    }
} else {
    echo "No categories!";
}
```

In case you're using **ACF image field** to add the featured image to the category, it's better to use [`get_field('featured_image', 'category_'.$catID)`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) instead of `get_term_meta()`. The code in that case depends on your field settings, so I encourage you to read the [documentation here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/).